# Nearest points from different id

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'd like to know how to get nearest points of the layer "a" to another point layer "b", using fields calculator of QGIS.
Layer "a" has points with 2 different id (1,2) and i want to get the closest points for each id.
For example:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried dissolving layer A based on the IDs and then running `join attributes by nearest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On layer `b`, use this expression to get the closest point on layer `a` with the same id. Use [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see [here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)):

```
with_variable (
    'id',
    id,
    eval (
    'overlay_nearest (
        ''a'', 
        $geometry,
        filter:= id = '  || 
        @id  || 
        ')[0]'
    )
)
```

*Sollution using Geometry generator: layer b = red points; layer a = blue points; red triangle = closest point on layer b from points of layer b with same id:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the field calculator in the **b** layer and paste this expression: `overlay_nearest('a_layer_id', $id)[0]`. Replace `a_layer_id` with the id of the **a** layer.

Comment: This doesn't work: first argument in `overlay_nearest` must be a layer name. And: I'm not sure if that is what OP is looking for - if they look to create an id in the attribute table of if the geometry should be rendered.

Comment: You are right, reading the question again, the result of this expression is not what was requested. About the ```overlay_nearest``` function, the first argument can be a name or an ID.